# Inserting a struct as a value in Multimap and Iterating the same to get the values

Tags: c++, struct, multimap

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
struct temp
{
   int x;
   int id;
};

int main()
{
    temp t;
    int key;
    typedef std::multimap<int,struct temp> mapobj;
    t.x = 10;
    t.id = 20;
    key=1;
    mapobj.insert(pair<int,struct>key,t);
    //mapobj.insert(1,t);
    
    return 0;
 }
```

I am new to STL multimap, I'm trying to insert my structure data inside the multimap but I get this error:

```
main.cpp:25:11: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
     mapobj.insert(pair<int,struct temp>key,t);
           ^
```

seeking your suggestion on this.

Comment: `typedef` declares a type alias, not a variable of the given type.

Comment: typedef std::multimap<int,struct temp> mapobj; need to change this as alias?

Comment: This is already an alias. Just remove the `typedef`.

Comment: Also note the typo(s) in `mapobj.insert(pair<int,struct>key,t);` and that you don't need the `struct` keyword when referring to a type.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you master `multimap<int, int>` before attempting this?

Comment: if i remove the alias "typedef" then i get the below error, main.cpp:25:19: error: ‘pair’ was not declared in this scope
     mapobj.insert(pair<int,struct>key,t);
                   ^~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make some minor code changes to fix the compile error as follows:

1. Add 2 brackets:   mapobj.insert(std::pair<int,struct temp> **(key,t) )**;
2. Add "struct **temp**" in mapobj.insert(std::pair<int,**struct temp**>(key,t));   (**Note**: You did not have the name of the struct: **temp**).
3. Please note that you should specify **std::pair** the second times you use **mapobj** at the bottom of your file.
4. Remove the keyword **Tydef** (as user "Sam Varshavchik" mentioned because you don't need to define a new type and you only need to define a new variable).
5. BTW, the following issue does not cause the compile error, but it will be a good thing if you initialize the value of "**key**" because if you do not initialize the value for "**key**", then **key** may have random values that is not zero. This is called undefined behavior, and it may cause some bug later on.

Here is the new code that compiles successfully:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
    
struct temp
{
   int x;
   int id;
};

int main()
{
    temp t;
    int key = 1; // You should initialize the key
    std::multimap<int,struct temp> mapobj; // I fixed this line
    t.x = 10;
    t.id = 20;
    key=1;
    mapobj.insert(std::pair<int,struct temp>(key,t)); // I fixed this line
    //mapobj.insert(1,t);
    
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I still see this error on compiling of the changed code as well,
   20 |     mapobj.insert(pair<int,struct temp>(key,t)); // I fixed this line
      |                   ^~~~
      |                   std::pair

Comment: @Ganesh Sha,   To fix that, we need to fully specify "std::pair" in "mapobj.insert(std::pair<int,struct temp>(key,t));"  -  I have just fixed that in the code, and it should compile now. Please try again and let me know.